# Does anyone have an idea how to get java cmd?

Tags: java, matlab

Does anyone have an idea how to change javacmd in this code
https://github.com/biocoder/SBEToolbox/blob/master/cytoscaperun.m

to get the new version of Cytoscape 3.2.1

```
syscmd = [javacmd ' -Xmx512m -jar "' addins_dir 'cytoscape'...
        path_slash 'cytoscape.jar" -network "' tmp_input_file ...
        '" -p "' addins_dir 'cytoscape' path_slash 'plugins" &'];
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the jar for Cytoscape 3.2.1 in your "addins_dir". You can find the jar here: [3.2.1](http://chianti.ucsd.edu/cytoscape-3.2.1/)

Make sure it's named "cytoscape.jar"

From the github project it appears the addins_dir is in SBEToolbox/addins

Note: You need to be careful replacing jars as there may be deprecated code and or changes to dependencies to other jars.